# YII2 Elasticsearch db configuration

Tags: php, elasticsearch, yii2

I have yii2 installed with Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana. The set-up is working well except for the interaction with YII2.

Below is the contents for `./config/db.php`

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
    'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\elasticsearch\Connection',
            'user' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'nodes' => [ ['http_address' => '127.0.0.1:9200'],
            // configure more hosts if you have a cluster
        ],
    ],
]
   ];
```

This configuration is not working, below are the first lines of the error.

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>
> The configuration for the "db" component must contain a "class"
>   element.
>
> 1. in /var/www/hostings/yiiphp/tools/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php

.....

I fail o find relevant information to fix this. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: show `ServiceLocator.php`.

Answer (score 0):

file `./config/db.php` should be included by the main config file, named `web` in your case (it seems that you are using basic app template)
Another words - look at file `./config/web.php` then find the line:
`'db' => ...` and replace it with `'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),`
Finally, your `db.php` should be like this:

```
<?php
return [
    'class' => 'yii\elasticsearch\Connection',
    'user' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'admin',
    'nodes' => [ ['http_address' => '127.0.0.1:9200'] ]
];
```

It is also seems strange to me, that you want to use `elastic` component as a db component, but its up to you, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in your config file:
'

```
elasticsearch' => [
            'class' => yii\elasticsearch\Connection::class,
            'auth' => ['username' => 'elastic', 'password' => 'changeme'],
            'nodes' => [
                ['http_address' => 'localhost:9200'],
                // configure more hosts if you have a cluster
            ],
            // set autodetectCluster to false if you don't want to auto detect nodes
            'autodetectCluster' => false,
            'dslVersion' => 7, // default is 5
        ],
```